# New Rails project -- Rails2 or Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compatibility, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this new project I need to build. I want to have at least started on it by the end of this month. So which version should I use though? Should I just stick with the stable Rails2 or try to use Rails3 so I won't have to migrate later? Which one would you suggest for someone that is still learning Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 3 definitely won't have the resources available for it that Rails 2 does, and Rails 3 will still be changing quite fast, so unless you're especially happy getting your support from the source code I'd stick with Rails 2

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already accepted Rails 2, but I'm throwing this out, anyway:

I've been using Rails 3 for my newer projects, and haven't noticed any significant bugs. Of course, I've only used popular gems and plugins that therefore are already have dedicated teams who have made them compatible with Rails 3.

You can fairly easily check if your plugins are compatible at [RailsPlugins.org](http://railsplugins.org/). Some might require you to use a specific Rails 3 branch from Github, so be sure to check the comments on reports that say "Working".

As long as you won't be using anything terribly obscure, you should be good to go for Rails 3, which is a fantastic piece of work from the Rails team. Arel makes my day every day.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 will not be out of beta sooner than fall this year and I guess it may shift. Rails 2 works pretty well and you will not need to debug unstable code while learning. Many tools, gems etc. have still not migrated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you both.

You should use rails2. Rails3 is still in beta and many problems can be encouter.

In my company we've migrate to rails3 and it's foolish.  We spend a lot of time to debug/modify plugins for rails3 ...

Now it's up to you to make your choice :)