# Is it worth the switch over from Rails 2 to Rails 3 if im starting a new application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is it worth the change from Rails 2 to 3 if im starting to work on a new application? are all the plug-ins and gems available for 2 now available for 3 as well? im used to developing and learning on Rails 2 and I'm afraid of switching over.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841921/new-rails-project-rails2-or-rails3 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965859/starting-a-new-project-should-i-go-with-rails-3-or-2-3-8/3965924 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the plugins you use work with Rails 3 [here](http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins).  Personally I'd say, if all the plugins that you use work with Rails 3 then you should upgrade, there are some nice [changes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) in Rails 3 that are worth using.

Answer (score 2):

I just started a Rails project a few weeks ago with Rails 3, and I've been quite happy so far.

Some gems/plugins don't quite work yet.  For example, Selenium and friends seem to be a little behind, though after trying a few plugins I finally got it working fine through [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).  [In_place_editing](https://github.com/rails/in_place_editing) isn't working out-of-the-box for me (I suspect because of Rails 3), though there are alternatives and it's not complex at all.  And I had some trouble with factory_girl, though apparently there is a [version for Rails 3](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) now.

But in general, most plugins I've tried seem to be working fine at this point.  Maarons has already pointed you at [RailsPlugins.org](http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins) if you want to check for a specific plugin.

Finally, there are bunch of things that are just better in Rails 3 (see the [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html)).  I used Rails 2 for a smaller project a while back, and using Rails 3 now, I was pleasantly surprised by the new routing (much less confusing), and the added bundler support (makes deploying much less scary).

Since you're setting up a new project, I'll also mention that I've been quite happy with Ruby 1.9.2 (as opposed to 1.8.7).  Check [PragDave's blog post](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2007/12/ruby-19right-fo.html) for some major changes.  The only thing that I recall needing explicit tinkering was the debugger -- just use the `ruby-debug19` gem and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Fear isn't a good enough reason not to switch.

There are quite a few plugins that **only** work on Rails 3, so I'd recommend starting a new project with 3, if you're starting now.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this question the other way around :)

If you are starting a new application then I'd say always try to go for the latest stable versions unless there is some really good reason not too.

Not only does it save you the trouble of migrating at a later stage (which in a likely hood will happen sooner or later), but you get to improve on a personal level as well by learning something new. And the later is something I find very important. If it's not challenging, it's not fun, and if it's not fun, then it's not gonna be good (for me at least).

As for all plug-ins and gems being available, probably not but the ones that are still being develped and improved will be if they are not already.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to switch eventually, so this is a good time. Why waste time on something you will have to change sooner or later? Rails ecosystem is quite responsive, and most plugins and gems are already 3.x compatible. Many have even deprecated 2.x support.